# wait for onSnapshot fetching data

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, react-native-firebase

I'm currently learning React Native (Expo).
I want to use redux and react-native-firebase.

When I subscribe to firebase (onSnapshot) at startup of my app, it returns the data from firebase. But since onSnapchot doesn't return a promise, I can't use it for my app-loading component.
Therefore, I also need to fetch the data from firebase to prevent the app from flicker.

The result is that at startup of my app I fetch the data twice.

So my question is:
How can I wait for onSnapshot loading my data from firebase?

Thanks

```js
const Manager = (props) => {
    //STATE
    const [init, setInit] = useState(false);

    //HOOKS
    const fetchData = useFetchData();
    useInitFirebaseSubscriptions();

    //FUNCTIONS
    async function onInit() {
        console.log('[MANAGER]: loading app...');
        await Promise.all([fetchData()]);
    }
    function onFinishedInit() {
        console.log('[MANAGER]: ...app loading successfull!');
        setInit(true);
    }

    //RETURN
    if (!init) {
        return <AppLoading startAsync={onInit} onFinish={onFinishedInit} onError={console.warn} />;
    } else {
        return props.children;
    }
};
export default Manager;
```

```js
//INITIAL FETCH BEFORE RENDERING
export function useFetchData() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return async function () {
        try {
            await firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => dispatch(actions.fetch(querySnapshot)));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    };
}
```

```js
//INIT SUBSCRIPTIONS TO FIREBASE
export function useInitFirebaseSubscriptions() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('[CONTROLLER]: subscribed to Firebase');
        const unsubscribe = firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .onSnapshot(
                (querySnapshot) => dispatch(action.fetch(querySnapshot)),
                (error) => console.log(error)
            );
        
        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
            console.log('[CONTROLLER]: unsubscribed from Firebase');
        };
    }, []);
}
```

```js
[MANAGER]: loading app...
[MANAGER]: subscribed to Firebase
[USER_REDUCER]: fetched data
[USER_REDUCER]: fetched data
[MANAGER]: ...app loading successfull!
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the `const fetchData = useFetchData();` hook and logic if the `useInitFirebaseSubscriptions` hook is fetching the data as well. What is the use case here, can you clarify? Seems an odd roundabout way to have a "loading" state, if I'm reading this correctly.

Comment: The firebase.get method is async, so I can wait for my useFetchData() Hook to finish before I render my UI. The result is that when the user open the app, the data is already there.
useInitFirebaseSubscriptions is not async, so I cannot wait with showing my UI until the data is fetched.. I hope it clear now

Comment: You can't wait for the data to populate in your redux store? You can't dispatch start/end fetching actions from the `useInitFirebaseSubscriptions` hook to indicate when you are actively fetching data?

Comment: Yes, that exactly is my question. 
How can I wait for the data from useInitFirebaseSubscriptions or how can I know if useInitFirebaseSubscriptions is still fetching data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish your goal by adding some "loading" state in redux for when you are actively fetching data from firebase. Add the state and reducer cases specific to this data fetching/loading.

Example code:

```js
export function useInitFirebaseSubscriptions() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[CONTROLLER]: subscribed to Firebase');

    dispatch(action.startFetch()); // <-- dispatch starting data fetch

    const unsubscribe = firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          dispatch(action.fetch(querySnapshot));
          dispatch(action.completedFetch()); // <-- done fetching
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          dispatch(action.completedFetch()); // <-- done fetching
        },
      );
        
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
      console.log('[CONTROLLER]: unsubscribed from Firebase');
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Select the loading state from the redux store and conditionally render the loading UI, otherwise render the passed children.

```js
const Manager = (props) => {
  const isFetchingData = useSelector(state => state.isFetchingData);

  if (isFetchingData) {
    return <AppLoadingIndicator />;
  }
  return props.children; // *
};
```

***** Generally you may use some additional conditional rendering here depending on if data was actually fetched/returned and is just empty, or if there was an error, etc... basically provide a bit of a result status.

Comment: great and easy solution, thank you. Haven't thought about using the callback from onSnapshot 

Comment: @sexpomicolon Yes, success/failure callbacks are sort of synonymous to `.then` and `.catch` of a Promise chain, and since there's no equivalent to `.finally` you unfortunately need to duplicate some "settled" logic in both handlers.